# Recommended reporting tool for smaller applications?

Tags: delphi, reporting

There are [quite a few VCLs for Delphi to build reports](http://www.vclcomponents.com/Delphi/Printing___Reporting/), so I'd like some feedback on which one to check.

It's just to build a few pages, ie. a microIVS application, so I don't need enterprise-level solutions. I don't expect any open-source tools, but if there's a good one out there...

I know about the following:

- Rave Reports, which ships with Delphi 2007
- QuickReports (I read that it used to ship with Delphi, but has been replaced by Rave Reports)
- FastReports
- Report Builder
- Crystal Report

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

My vote goes to [Fast Report](http://www.fast-report.com/). We have used Quick Report in Delphi 5 and 7, Rave and List & Label in Delphi 7 (only for a short time), now we are moving to Fast Report which supports Delphi 2009. It is a great product and the support is very good.

Comment: +1 - I have been using FastReports in a commercial product for some time now, and even duplicated the reporting engine against crystal reports.  Using FastReports our support for reports went way down...to the point that we abandoned crystal reports completely.  The engine just works, and having Delphi source allows you to dig in and find any problems which occur that are not obvious.  Extending to create reports from any data is simple.

Comment: Thanks guys. I started learning FastReports, and it does seem like a good solution, in terms of features and price. Note that FreeReport is not available for Delphi2007+.

Answer (score 2):

There's [FreeReport](http://fast-report.com/en/products/free-report-generator-for-delphi.html) from same company who produced [FastReport](http://fast-report.com/en/products/report-generator-for-delphi-fastreport-4.html), if you don't need to much work on reports or complex reports you can use it, and upgrade later to FR.

But my vote for [FastReport](http://fast-report.com/en/products/report-generator-for-delphi-fastreport-4.html), it's very easy and you can build the complex reports without a lot of works.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need anything heavy-duty, why not just go with Rave, seeing as how it's already included with Delphi?

Comment: Rave is quite heavy-duty as you can create really complex reports with it (but the docs are really not in same league with the product itself)...

Answer (score 0):

[ReportBuilder Standard](http://www.digital-metaphors.com/products/standard.html) is feature rich, easy to use and well supported. There are more advanced editions available as well if you need more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at report manager at http://reportman.sourceforge.net/